# What is the best way to writing a method which execution time more than 5 min?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a java method which execute every midnight. The method perform backup data from one table1 to another table2 and clear table1. Everyday table1 contain 13214215 rows.

**This is my scheduler method**

```
    @Scheduled(cron = "0 59 23 * * *")
    public void doAutoBackupProcess() {

        try {
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
            headers.add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36");

            HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>("parameters", headers);

            String url = "http://192.168.31.5:8082/scheduler/attendance/backup/call";

            restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, Object.class);
            logger.info("Data Backup success");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SchedulerService.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

**http://192.168.31.5:8082/scheduler/attendance/backup/call**
*contain below method*

```
    @Transactional
    public void doStdAttendanceBackup() {

        List<StudentAttendanceDetails> sads = studentAttendanceDetailsRepository.findAll();     
        studentAttendanceDetailsBackUpRepository.save(copyStudentAttendanceDetailsToStdAttendanceDetailsBackUp(sads));      
        studentAttendanceDetailsRepository.delete(sads);
    }



public List<StdAttendanceDetailsBackUp> copyStudentAttendanceDetailsToStdAttendanceDetailsBackUp(List<StudentAttendanceDetails> sads) {

        List<StdAttendanceDetailsBackUp> sadbus = sads.stream().map((sad) -> {
            StdAttendanceDetailsBackUp sadbu = new StdAttendanceDetailsBackUp();
            BeanUtils.copyProperties(sad, sadbu);
            return sadbu;
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
        return sadbus;
    }
```

When execute Above method then I face

> *java.lang.outofmemoryerror gc overhead limit exceeded*

and

> *java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space*

Exception. I increase java heap memory in jvm 2256m
but problem not solve

Any one give me a best solution ?
Thanks

Comment: Select sleep(301)

Comment: Sir kindly describe your answer ?

Answer (score 2):

The solution to back up all data at once doesn't scale. For this reason you should paginate in reading (and deleting) more times.

```
boolean migratedElements = false;

//if you delete your data, you can page every time first 1000 records or 10000... this can be tuned
Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(0, 1000);

while(!migratedElements) {

    List<StudentAttendanceDetails> sads1000 = studentAttendanceDetailsRepository.findAll(pageable);  

    if(sads1000.size() == 0) {
        migratedElements = true;
    } else {
        studentAttendanceDetailsBackUpRepository.save(copyStudentAttendanceDetailsToStdAttendanceDetailsBackUp(sads));      
        studentAttendanceDetailsRepository.delete(sads);
    }  

}
```

You need also to call your backup rest service for every page or you can encounter still in outOfMemory

Answer (score 0):

There are too many methods to implement it, F.Y.I.

1. JDBC Fetch Stream

Here is an example:

```
@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

public void doStdAttendanceBackup() {

    String sql = "select * from *** where c=:c1 and b=:b1";
    jdbcTemplate.setFetchSize(1000); 
    NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(jdbcTemplate);

    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>(2);
    params.put("c1", ***);
    params.put("b1", ***);

    namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(sql, params, (ResultSet rs) -> {
        // 0. copy rs to StdAttendanceDetailsBackUp;

        // 1. save StdAttendanceDetailsBackUp;

        // 2  delete StudentAttendanceDetails;

        // note: makesure the codes is transactional above
    });
}
```

2. Insert into Select

Please refer :https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp

I think the second way is better for you if the two tables are belong to one db user.